# Встроенный поиск от Google для сайта

Tags: предложение, поиск

Я предлагал это для ХэшКода, теперь предлагаю сделать здесь.
Пример: я хочу найти дубликат вопроса:

[Как сделать такой скрипт на своем сайте?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/433223/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bf%d1%82-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b5?lq=1)

Делаю такой запрос гуглу:

[Google: id как в vk](https://www.google.ru/search?q=site%3Aru.stackoverflow.com+id+%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA+%D0%B2+vk&oq=site%3Aru.stackoverflow.com+id+%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA+%D0%B2+vk&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i58.13812j0j4&sourceid=chrome-mobile&espv=1&ie=UTF-8)

А теперь сравните релевантность выдачи с [оригинальным поиском по сайту](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=id+%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA+%D0%B2+vk)

---

Google профессионал в поиске релевантных данных. Предлагаю добавить поиск от профессионалов на сайт- не очень приятно каждый поиск писать:

```
site:ru.stackoverflow.com
```

Comment: думаю проще настроить поиск в браузере.

Comment: @ReinRaus: Вы ещё не пользуетесь шорткатами для поиска? <s>Тогда мы идём к вам!</s> `so id как в vk` -> `https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Aru.stackoverflow.com+%s` (Вот [для лисички](http://www-archive.mozilla.org/docs/end-user/keywords.html) и [для хрома](http://graywolfseo.com/google/how-to-add-search-shortcuts-to-google-chrome/)).